# Eclipse with GWT: InsantiationError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.<init>

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jetty, smartgwt

I have been using my Eclipse with GWT 2.6 without problems.  Today I decided to upgrade to use GWT 2.8

After having made quite some change to my Eclipse (including downloading the newer GWT SDK for 2.8.1), I got this error.  (I was using the regular Dev Mode with GWT 2.6 and the new Super Dev Mode with GWT 2.8)

```
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to DEBUG or WARN to see all errors.
   Ignored 11 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Module setup completed in 79501 ms
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:121)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:162)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:55)
```

I thought maybe my Eclipse was too old, so I upgraded it to 4.7 (Oxygen). (My old Eclipse was 4.4 (Luna)).  But then I still got a similar error message:

```
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Module setup completed in 13875 ms
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:121)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:161)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:102)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas on why I would get this error?

Comment: Any chance you have other jetty versions or jars on the classpath outside of what GWT provides? That seems most likely without more information. Also, consider skipping 2.8.1 since 2.8.2 fixes some issues and seems rather stable.

Comment: @Colin -- Thanks a lot!  It does seems to be the problem.  Now I got pass that problem (but hit another one).  I can provide a more detailed answer later.  As for 2.8.2, on Eclipse Marketplace, I could only for "GWT Eclipse Plugin" with "GWT 2.8.1 SDK".  I need to figure out how to find "GWT 2.8.2 SDK"